# Signing a jar file with a PKCS certificate (.spc)

Tags: java, applet, certificate, keytool

I don't have a lot of experience with Java or Certificates and I am finding myself in a very bad situation concerning the signing of a java jar file (it's an applet). I was given the task because no one else here is any better at it than me. I apologize if this is a duplicate question but none of the fixes I found seem to work for me. Ditto with my Google searches, which all seem to require an in depth knowledge of certificates and the tools for handling them.

I was hoping someone could walk me through the steps of:
1. Creating a keystore that could later import a PKCS #7(#12?) certificate.
2. Having it generate a public key to send to the certificate website (GoDaddy).
3. Import the PKCS certificate into the keystore.
4. Sign the jar file.

The site my CA gave me is either out of date or just wrong.

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4780/java-code-signing-generating-a-csr

I am hoping it's all possible using the java keytool utility. I also have a win32 version of openssl if needed.

This has been a real headache for me and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keytool and jarsigner just like those directions indicate.  Make sure when you get the certificate signed it is authorized for code signing.  Note that with recent versions of java, there are also attributes required to be in the manifest to permit your code to run without warnings.  Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html) for more information.

Comment: Which approach in the instructions 1 or 2? I have a manifest file ready.

Comment: If I should use approach 2 (I tried Approach 1 and it was a no go), how do I make the mycert.pfx file? It just pops out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a lot of time on this, I had an epiphany.

1. Go to GoDaddy.com.
2. Cancel your certificate.
3. Go to DigitCert.com (or any other certificate authority that sells X509 DER certificates.
4. Buy the type of certificate that your keystore will accept.
5. Follow the simple instructions the certificate authority gives you.
6. Enjoy the rest of your day!